# Access to top domain cookies from subdomain application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My vbulletin forum sets some cookies on `domain-name.com`, and I'd like to read these cookies within my rails app which is on `beta.domain-name.com`. How can I do this?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies

Comment: Your rails app is a server app that sets the cookies for client browser. What do you mean by 'reading' the cookies?

Comment: I answer it already, when I manually set cookies from `domain-name.com` I couldnt read them in app, changing domain to `.domain-name.com` helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you set cookie's domain to: `.domain-name.com` (dot at the beginning), you can access it's cookies from subdomains, if domain is `domain-name.com` (withouth dot at the beginning) you can access it's cookies only from this domain.